# How come the weight paint isn't symmetrical?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

My character has mirror modifier turned on and I used automatic weight paint to properly rig my armature to the model and I thought it would be 50% to 50% on both sides but it feels like one side has more control which makes the mesh uneven causing some clipping deforms. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file?

Comment: share with https://blend-exchange.com/ or use a platform like workupload

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5jw5p4R0" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5jw5p4R0/)

Comment: It doesn't give the same result, see: https://zupimages.net/up/22/47/xvij.jpg

Comment: Interesting what did you do? did you change something or was everything the same?

Comment: no i didn't change anything